# How do I use named constructors in C++ using constructor delegates?

Tags: c++, class, types, constructor, delegation

Say I have a constructor and a delegated constructor

```
SomeClass(const std::string&& _name) : obj_needs_construction(100), name(_name) {}
SomeClass(const std::string& _name) : SomeClass(_name) {}
```

But both are using the same type, I've seen many solutions but they all seem to operate because they make different types but that won't work in my situation. How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: `const std::string&&` is pretty useless. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If I'm just using that string just for the constructor I shouldn't need it anymore? Or will it get optimized away anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SomeClass(const std::string& _name) : SomeClass(std::move(_name)) {}
```

Comment: This works, but it may not be worth using delegates because it's making my code more confusing which is the opposite of my goal.

Comment: @ThomasStiteler, that's your call.

Comment: Chosen as answer because it's the answer even though I won't use delegating

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
SomeClass(const std::string&& _name) : obj_needs_construction(100), name(_name) {}
SomeClass(const std::string& _name) : SomeClass(_name) {}
```

… with just

```
SomeClass( std::string const& name )
    : obj_needs_construction( 100 )
    , name_( name )
{}
```

That's it. It will work nicely for temporaries as actual arguments.

Comment: My example only included one constructor but I actually have a lot more and to clean up code I am using a delegated constructor, so that's why I'm not just using that.

Comment: Well, you won't get answers about issues that you don't even mention.